# create bar chart using python showing data weekly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have prepared excel sheet using python. It has a column which represents date. What i need is to plot a chart weekly by grouping data week wise where y axis should show count week wise and x axis should show week number . Can someone please help. This is what i have till now

df = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\hasolank\PycharmProjects\flask\files\jobs_cd_prd_all.xlsx")
df["duration"] = pd.to_datetime(df['duration'])
df.set_index('duration').resample('W')["name"].count()

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: and for some people who are asking to share what have you done till now so please find below

Comment: df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\hasolank\\PycharmProjects\\flask\\files\\jobs_cd_prd_all.xlsx")
    df["duration"] = pd.to_datetime(df['duration'])
    df.set_index('duration').resample('W')["name"].count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html).

```
# make sure `duration` column is datetime type
df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['duration'])
# create a Series, grouping by week
weekly_series = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='duration', freq='W'))['name'].count()
# replace datetimes with the week number
weekly_series.index = weekly_series.index.week
# and plot it
weekly_series.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: thanks it is working...but can i rename week numbers to week 1 , week 2 and so on ....instead of week 39 , week 40 . can it be possible ?